# When Lightning Knowledge is enabled, you can't add an article type

Tags: managed-package, knowledge, 2gp

I am trying to install my package into our demo org and received this error:

```
ERROR:  Encountered errors installing the package!,Installation errors: 
1) (Knowledge__kav) When Lightning Knowledge is enabled, you can’t add an article type., Details: Knowledge__kav: When Lightning Knowledge is enabled, you can’t add an article type.
```

I didn't think I was adding an article type. What can I check to see if I am?

Or, is there something else I can try to get my package to install?

Other potentially relevant information:

- This is a 2nd generation managed package
- The org is a partner developer org that was created through the PBO's environment hub
- The org has Knowledge and Lightning Knowledge successfully enabled

Answer (score 0):

there is a KI referenced to this, please follow below article and work around provided:

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001Sp9SQAS&title=error-message-update-for-lightning-knowledge-enablement-is-blocked-when-the-article-type-is-part-of-an-unmanaged-package

Thank you

Comment: There are several differences between what we're trying and what that article describes. The org in question is already has Lightning Knowledge enabled, we're not migrating it to Lightning Knowledge. This is a managed package, not an unmanaged package. The package is also not installed in on the org yet, so we can't uninstall it.